# SQL server 'like' against a float field produces inconsistent results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `LIKE` to return matching numeric results against a float field.  It seems that once there are more than 4 digits to the left of the decimal, values that match my search item on the right side of the decimal are not returned.  Here's an example illustrating the situation:

```
CREATE TABLE number_like_test (
  num [FLOAT] NULL
)

INSERT INTO number_like_test (num) VALUES (1234.56)
INSERT INTO number_like_test (num) VALUES (3457.68)
INSERT INTO number_like_test (num) VALUES (13457.68)
INSERT INTO number_like_test (num) VALUES (1234.76)
INSERT INTO number_like_test (num) VALUES (23456.78)

SELECT num FROM number_like_test
WHERE num LIKE '%68%'
```

That query does not return the record with the value of 12357.68, but it does return the record with the value of 3457.68.  Also running the query with 78 instead of 68 does not return the 23456.78 record, but using 76 returns the 1234.76 record.

So to get to the question: why having a larger number causes these results to change?  How can I change my query to get the expected results?

Comment: **Do not use `LIKE` against numbers.**  It's a string comparison used for strings.

Comment: @JNK, what if the numeric values are cast to strings?

Comment: You could do that I guess but why on earth are you?

Comment: I need to match some user search item against numeric fields, where the results they want match 'like'. What's the alternative?

Comment: Like is not the problem here. It can work fine with numbers, implicit conversion to string will occur. Float is the problem, as it is approximate datatype - you should switch to decimal or at least cast it to decimal before comparing it.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4730

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, yes, you are right. The answer to here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950705/using-like-to-match-floats-when-rounding-is-not-wanted) seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `like` operator requires a string as a left-hand value.  According to the documentation, a conversion from `float` to `varchar` can use [several styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
Value         Output
0 (default)   A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
1             Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
2             Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
```

The default style will work fine for the six digits in `3457.68`, but not for the seven digits in `13457.68`.  To use 16 digits instead of 6, you could use `convert` and specify style 2.  Style 2 represents a number like `3.457680000000000e+003`.  But that wouldn't work for the first two digits, and you get an unexpected `+003` exponent for free.

The best approach is probably a conversion from `float` to `decimal`.  That conversion allows you to specify the scale and precision.  Using scale 20 and precision 10, the float is represented as `3457.6800000000`:

```
where   convert(decimal(20,10), num) like '%68%'
```

Comment: Good answer, even with it working with the decimal convert, this fills in the question of why it doesn't work due to the number of digits.  Is the outer convert to varchar really needed?

Comment: Good point, it looks like the outer convert is not required.  The implicit conversion from `decimal` to `varchar` doesn't drop digits.

Comment: Great answer!  5 years later this just saved me so much time and headache lol

Answer (score 2):

When you are comparing number with LIKE it is implicitly converted to string and then matched

The problem here is that float number is not precise and when it is converted you can get 
13457.679999999999999 instead of 13457.68

So to avid this explicitly format number in appropriate format(not sure how to do this in sql server, but it will be something like)

```
SELECT num FROM number_like_test
WHERE Format("0.##",num) LIKE '%68%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The conversion to string is rounding your values. Both `CONVERT` and `CAST` have the same behavior.

```
SELECT cast(num as nvarchar(50)) as s
FROM number_like_test
```

**Or**

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(50), num) as s
FROM number_like_test
```

provide the results:

```
1234.56
3457.68
13457.7
1234.76
23456.8
```

You'll have to use the `STR` function and correct format parameters to try to get your results. For example,

```
SELECT STR(num, 10, 2) as s
FROM number_like_test
```

gives:

```
   1234.56
   3457.68
  13457.68
   1234.76
  23456.78
```

Comment: But using either of those values (cast or convert) in the where clause with the like still gives the wrong results.  I need to cast to decimal (like NenadZivkovic commented) because of the precision of the float datatype.

Comment: @rosscj2533 - Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Casting to decimal is probably the right way to go, but using STR with the correct format parameters is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty well solved already, but you only need to CAST once, not twice like the other answer suggests, LIKE takes care of the string conversion:

```
SELECT *
FROM number_like_test
WHERE CAST(num AS DECIMAL(12,6)) LIKE '%68%'
```

And here's a SQL Fiddle showing the rounding behavior: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaaf7/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because a FLOAT data type represents a [floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) which is an approximation of the number and should not be relied on for exact comparisons.

If you need to do a search that includes the float value you would need to either store it in a decimal data type (which will hold the exact number) or convert it to a varchar using something like [the STR() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)