# Using LIKE Operator on a Float Data Type for Partial Search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data set stored as a `float` data type in TableA:

```
    DataColumn
    ----------
    1234554554
    2566854545
    9845684585
    6399421226
```

Now when I execute a select statement using a `like` operator in search of the exact pattern I do get the result back e.g:

```
select * from TableA where DataColumn='2566854545'
```

Will output the desired result of:

```
2566854545
```

But now when I want to do a partial search with values towards the end of the pattern I get 0 results all the time i.e:

```
select * from TableA where convert(nvarchar, DataColumn)  LIKE '%545'
```

This does not find any records. I also tried to cast it to an nvarchar but also I get the same result. I had a look at [Like operator for integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462376/like-operator-for-integer) and [SQL server 'like' against a float field produces inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069895/sql-server-like-against-a-float-field-produces-inconsistent-results) but still nothing.

Any suggestions on where I may be going wrong?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited the post to include the DBMS.

Comment: Why is this column of integers using float datatype anyway?

Comment: Look at the result of your conversion : select convert(nvarchar, DataColumn) from TableA   - Being decimal it wouldn't be surprising if you have some 0 decimals trailing.

Comment: @Marc Guillot but the convert function returns an nvarchar. Where does a decimal come into play here?

Comment: @Martin I defined this column as a float because I getting the values from excel which comes as an exponential value of base 10. I'm avoiding losing precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you should argue why cast doesn't work).  Added a second version, for decimal values.  Pls pay attention at performances (functions in where clause can cause not use of an eventual existent index on the column).

```
 CREATE TABLE #tt1 (DATA FLOAT);
    INSERT INTO #tt1 VALUES (2556668545);

    SELECT DATA, STR(DATA) AS D2, CAST(DATA AS VARCHAR(20)) D3 FROM  #tt1
where STR(DATA)  LIKE '%666%'
```

Output:

```
DATA                   D2         D3
---------------------- ---------- --------------------
2556668545             2556668545 2.55667e+009
```

Added version (based on decimal values, not showed in your question):

```
CREATE TABLE #tt1 (DATA FLOAT);
INSERT INTO #tt1 VALUES (2556668545);
INSERT INTO #tt1 VALUES (1234554554);
INSERT INTO #tt1 VALUES (1234554554.8789345);

SELECT DATA, CAST( CAST(DATA AS NUMERIC(38,10)) AS VARCHAR(40)) AS D2
 FROM  #tt1
where CAST( CAST(DATA AS NUMERIC(38,10)) AS VARCHAR(40))  LIKE '%89%'
```

Output

```
DATA                   D2
---------------------- ----------------------------------------
1234554554.87893       1234554554.8789344000
```

Comment: Your solution works but when I run it against my actual data it still does not return any records

Comment: Can you post some data (if different from what you posted above) ?

Comment: Post data values that are not returned by the query

Comment: It returns 0 results

Comment: See my answer: I posted a complete script with sample data: DO THE SAME otherwise it's very hard to help you...