# 'LIKE' issues with FLOAT: SQL query needed to find values >= 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a conundrum....

There is a table with one <strike>NVARCHAR(50)</strike>  **Float** column that has many rows with many numbers of various decimal lengths:

- '3304.063'
- '3304.0625'
- '39.53'
- '39.2'

I need to write a query to find only numbers with decimal places >= 4

First the query I wrote was:

```
SELECT
     Column
FROM Tablename
WHERE Column LIKE '%.[0-9][0-9]%'
```

The above code finds all numbers with decimal places >= 2:

- '3304.063'
- '3304.0625'
- '39.53'

**Perfect!** Now, I just need to increase the [0-9] by 2...

```
SELECT
     Column
FROM Tablename
WHERE Column LIKE '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

this returned nothing! What?

Does anyone have an explanation as to what went wrong as well and/or a possible solution? I'm kind of stumped and my hunch is that it is some sort of 'LIKE' limitation..

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: I can't [reproduce this behavior](http://rextester.com/BLWXM31557).  Maybe your data has some problems.

Comment: I concur with @TimBiegeleisen, I can't [reproduce either](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1128c8ce0aa0c483570e23e5f23846ba)

Comment: If you still can't figure it out show us `select column, cast(column as varbinary(max)) from Tablename` for a row you think should match but does not (to identify any unicode shenanigans).

Comment: What happens if the final digit is a zero? Should patindex be '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]%' instead? Currently, the casting as decimal and keeping as varchar solutions are give different results depending on this.

Comment: Thank you all for your analysis, but I gave you bad data! The column is not NVARCHAR but is instead Float. You will see two issues now - 1 being the number not displaying, and 2. the number left of the decimal only goes up to 99 after casting the column to a NVARCHAR(50)..

Comment: keep them as float and try `where len(column - floor(column)) >= 6` (compare lengths of the mantissa)

Comment: In that case, here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17069895/6167855 and you should use `DECIMAL` and not use the `LIKE` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit, you stated you are using [`FLOAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which is an approximate value stored as 4 or 8 bytes, or 7 or 15 digits of precision. The documents explicitly state that not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly. It also states you can use the [`STR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function when converting it which you'll need to get your formatting right. Here is how:

```
declare @table table (columnName float)

insert into @table
values
('3304.063'),
('3304.0625'), 
('39.53'),
('39.2')


--see the conversion
select * , str(columnName,20,4)
from @table

--now use it in a where clause. 
--Return all values where the last digit isn't 0 from STR() the conversion
select  *
from @table
where right(str(columnName,20,4),1) != 0
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Your `LIKE` statement would do it, and here is another way just to show they both work.

```
declare @table table (columnName varchar(64))

insert into @table
values
('3304.063'),
('3304.0625'),
('39.53'),
('39.2')

select *
from @table
where len(right(columnName,len(columnName) - charindex('.',columnName))) >= 4

select *
from @table
where columnName like '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

One thing that could be causing this is a space in the number somewhere... since you said the column type was `VARCHAR` this is a possibility, and could be avoided by storing the value as `DECIMAL`

```
declare @table table (columnName varchar(64))

insert into @table
values
('3304.063'),
('3304. 0625'), --notice the space here
('39.53'),
('39.2')

--this would return nothing
select *
from @table
where columnName like '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

How to find out if this is the case?

```
select *
from @table
where columnName like '% %'
```

Or, anything but numbers and decimals:

```
select *
from @table
where columnName like '%[^.0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers and analysis. Mystery solved; however cryptic :)

Comment: No worries @MikeDee just stick to decimal and you’re solid :)

Comment: This will fail if the number has more than 4 digits after the decimal, but happens to end with zero when rounded to 4 digits.  Example:   3.000025

Comment: Correct @DavidDubois due to the conversion. This is a limitation of converting FLOAT. we’d have to check for the substring if all values after the fourth to be > 1 but the OP didn’t give the largest possible number so I just went with 4 as an example

Answer (score 0):

The following is working fine for me:

```
declare @tab table (val varchar(50))
insert into @tab 
select '3304.063'
union select '3304.0625'
union select '39.53'
union select '39.2'

select * from @tab
where val like '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table only has numerical data, you can cast them to decimal and then compare:

```
SELECT COLUMN 
FROM tablename 
WHERE CAST(COLUMN AS DECIMAL(19,4)) <> CAST(COLUMN AS DECIMAL(19,3))
```

You'd want to test the performance of this against using the character data type solutions that others have already suggested.

Comment: This could be wrong, or the only right answer. It removes final zeros in the string.

Comment: It works for majority of the numbers, but since my column is float I get an arithmetic overflow error! Giving you +1 as I gave bad data at first :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REVERSE:

```
declare @vals table ([Val] nvarchar(50))
insert into @vals values ('3304.063'), ('3304.0625'), ('39.53'), ('39.2')

select [Val]
from @Vals
where charindex('.',reverse([Val]))>4
```